# Bullet drop in Far Cry 3 ?

Tags: far-cry-3

Does Far Cry 3 incorporate bullet drop phenomenon ?

I always aim a bit higher in very long distance sniping, but don't always get a shot. I'm not sure but I don't think bullet drop is present or maybe very little ? How high am I supposed to aim at 200m+ away ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I am aware the only weapons that are effected by gravity are the bow-and-arrow (plus special arrows) and the projectiles (Molotovs and Grenades) - at least in Xbox version.

In fact, it has been [discussed on FC3 forums](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/733982-Sniper-maximum-range-Forums) that the bullets actually disappear after 250 meters anyway, long before bullet drop would occur.

I have been curious about gravity in FC3 myself, but testing with the sniper rifle from quite a distance I can still get headshots by aiming directly at the head, and miss if I aim higher (although it could be that I'm a bad shot too).

Also, I have never noticed any difference in accuracy in different weather conditions, or between day and night (not that I would expect it their either).

It's pretty much just a case of pointing at who you want to kill and pressing the trigger, and you hit them.

Comment: I can confirm this with my findings as well. ( on Xbox )

Comment: [On PS3 the maximum distance seems to be just over 150 meters.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/107057/5398)

Answer (score 0):

Ps3 doesn't have any sign of bullet drop, but maybe on pc. Btw If your using a high power scope ignore the lines used to calculate bullet drop. Personally I think they are for show. It's also a kick in the nads for players expecting some realism.

Comment: I think if you came to this looking for realism, you should maybe go back to Arma. This has gun vending machines in it. That nobody ever breaks into.